# What are the steps to create a relational database of a school?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

A school has many subjects: subject1, subject2, subject3 etc, many students enrolled for one or many subjects and there are teachers. Each teacher teaches one subject only.

Now I'm asked to make a website for the school. But I'm not good at relational database, I know how to join tables, but I'm stuck in what and how many tables to be created. I know there will be a student, teacher and a class table, with their id, name etc.

But what will be my approach so that I can access all data? I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: The key, as per Thomas' answer, is to decide (a) what are the entities in the system (subject, student, teacher etc) and (b) what are the relationships (1:1, 1:many, many:many).

Comment: (Incidentally, questions that are broad and do not contain a prior attempt are likely to be put on hold as off-topic - it's worth having a read of the help section when you get a moment).

Comment: I tried to find , but i wanted a clear structure as what to be done, once i get one picture the idea will be clear, but there are so detailed topics of relational database that i had to post a question for the quick easily understandable steps

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately, it is still not a good fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with this simple design:

**student**: id, name, ...

**teacher**: id, name, ...

**subject**: id, name, ...

**class**: id, subject_id , teacher_id

**enrollment**: id, class_id , student_id

This assumes:

1. Any teacher can teach any subject
2. A teacher can teach in more than one class
3. A student can enroll in more than one class
4. There are no concepts like "semester". That would affect table **class**

You probably (but I'm not sure) don't want to allow a student to enroll in two different classes with the same subject. You can control that with PHP (querying if the student is already enrolled in a class with the subjet requested), or a SQL trigger. You can try to tweak this design to prohibit that combination right from the schema.

Finally, there are many many other considerations not taken here. For instance, teachers can come and go, and be available or not. Some subjects often require others to be passed before you enroll, etc.

This is just a simple way to start.

Answer (score 1):

it really depend of what you need, but you can do it like that:

```
subject: id, name

student: id, firstname, lastname

teacher: id, firstname, lastname

rel_subject : id_subject, id_people, type_people
```

and if you need to plan schedule

```
class: id, id_subject, time, place
```